# Need help constructing consistent sentences, and naming parts

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I'm a software developer and I'm trying to write a consistent "grammar" for an audit log feature. An Audit log is basically a list of actions that happened in the past.

As it's a part of the database I need consistent naming for the parts of the sentences. Now I'm not natively english, so I could use some help.

In each example sentence below I appended a number to some words. Each of these words should be of the same "type" (e.g.: subject, object, ... other).

- Anna[1] created[2] the_comment[4] on the_article[3]
- Mark[1] voted[2] on the video[3]
- Jessy[1] signed_in[2]
- John[1] added[2] Jessy[4] to the list[3]
- Anna[3] was blocked[2] by Dick[1]
- Louis[1] replied[2] to the_conversation[3] with his_message[4]

I'm pretty sure 1: is the subject, and 2: is the verb.
However I don't know how I should name 3 and 4, and I have a suspicion some sentence constructions should change.

Could you help me out?

Comment: Among objects, we have direct object & indirect object. From that lead, you may want to rethink which you would label [3] and which [4]. That should make things a bit clearer to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anna[1](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/diagrams/diagrams.htm) created[2] the_comment[4] on the_article[3] 
 4= direct object, 3 = object of the preposition *on*

Mark[1](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/diagrams/diagrams.htm) voted[2] on the video[3]
3 = prepositional phrase modifying *voted*

Jessy[1](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/diagrams/diagrams.htm) signed_in[2]

John[1](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/diagrams/diagrams.htm) added[2] Jessy[4] to the list[3]
4 = direct object 3 = *to the list* is a prepositional phrase modifying *added*

Anna[3] was blocked[2] by Dick[1](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/diagrams/diagrams.htm) 
3 = is the subject of the passive verb *was blocked*  Note, *Dick* is not the subject.

Louis[1](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/diagrams/diagrams.htm) replied[2] to the_conversation[3] with his_message[4]  3 and 4 are the objects of the prepositions *to* and *on*

I hope I have answered your question.  If you are familiar with a process no longer commonly taught in the USA called "diagraming sentences" it is a graphic way of answering the kind of questions you've asked.  Here is a link you might find helpful [Diagraming Sentences](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/diagrams/diagrams.htm)